# Javascript added to head but unable to use it

Tags: javascript

I have a toggle switch that when i press it adds a Javascript to the head of the page:

```
    function yourcallback (){
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'dev/additional_script.js';
head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Now when i use firebug to debug it i can see all of the scripts however if i try to call a function to that script it tells me that the function i am trying to call is undefined.

So it would seem that the script is not loaded correctly.

HOWEVER if i in firebug try and call the same function it returns `function()`
meaning that it should be defined.

Has anyone experianced anything like this and / or know how i can fix it.

please tell me if  you need more code information and il add it to my question

**update**

Okay so here is the thing i have two scripts:

1. The script that controls the switch button (when the user press it another script will be loaded)
2. the script that is loaded when the script button is pressed ( this is where the function is located.

In script one i am trying to call a function in script 2 after it has been loaded and this is where i am getting the error:

The way i am calling the function is just using the function name

The function i am trying to access looks like this:

```
    var init = function() {
    var i, anchors, scriptTag;

    //get the uid...
    scriptTag = document.getElementById("link-replacer");
    if(scriptTag) {
        uid = scriptTag.getAttribute("data-uid");
    } else {
        uid = "none";
    }
    urlpart = forwardUrl+"?uid="+uid+"&url=";

    if(doOnLoadReplace) {
        anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for(i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
            fixHref(anchors[i]);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: how are you calling the function in the script?

Comment: @sevenseacat i have a function called init(); first i load the script and then i just call init();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
        var myScript = document.createElement('script');
        myScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        myScript.setAttribute('src', 'dev/additional_script.js');
        var headFirst = document.getElementsByTagName('head');
        headFirst[0].appendChild(myScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're adding the script incorrectly. Try this:

```
var newJS = document.createElement('script');
newJS.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
newJS.setAttribute('src', 'dev/additional_script.js');
```